# Can a Tiger get two attacks in a round and a possible third with pounce?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack

Tigers get a bite attack and a claw attack along with this:

> **Pounce.** If the tiger moves at least 20 feet straight toward a creature right before hitting it with a claw attack, the target must succeed on a DC 13 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the tiger can take a bonus action to make one bite attack against it.

If the tiger moves at least 20 feet can they bite then use claw attack and get a possible second bite attack if the target fails the save?

Comment: Can you cite the source of this description? Because it seems to be wrong, the actual one is: "[...] and then hits it with a claw attack *on the same turn, [...]". See [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tiger).

Answer (score 25):

### No

The stat block for a tiger lists these actions:

> **Actions**
>
> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 8 (1d10 + 3) >piercing damage.
>
> Claw. Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 7 (1d8 + 3) slashing damage.

Compare this to the stat block of a polar bear:

> **Actions**
>
> Multiattack. The bear makes two attacks: one with its bite and one with its claws.
>
> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +7 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 9 (1d8 + 5) >piercing damage.
>
> Claws. Melee Weapon Attack: +7 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 12 (2d6 + 5) slashing damage.

The tiger stat block lacks the multiattack option which would allow both a claw and a bite attack. They could normally only use both during the same turn if they moved at least 20 feet towards their target, then made a successful claw attack and had the target fail their save, before using making the bite attack as a bonus action. Aside from that it would require some special effect like the haste spell to allow it.

Comment: Precisely, a creature has one action per round (unless a feature gives them another) and each attack uses that action.

Comment: Stat blocks list multiple attack types sometimes as flavour, and sometimes because they are facing something immune to one damage type or the like.  The tiger would usually just bite; but both the special ability and special circumstances could make it claw instead (like, suppose you have a tiger in a muzzle or only able to reach a claw through a hole).